# Black Image: pylon_camera

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, camera-drivers, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Resonon Pika L which has pylon camera(hyperspectral) and using it with Pylon ROS package. I followed the article available at "http://wiki.ros.org/pylon_camera" to setup the pylon ROS package.

After running 'rosrun pylon_camera pylon_camera_node', I run 'rosrun image_view image_view image:=/pylon_camera_node/image_raw' But I am only getting black image.

I also checked the data published to '/pylon_camera_node/image_raw' topic. It is just a matrix full of 0's. So I am not sure how to see the images from the camera. I am new to ROS. I can see some gray-line images using PylonViewerApp

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297917/black-image:-pylon_camera/) by [Jazzscout](https://answers.ros.org/users/36218/jazzscout/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You tried to use the PylonViewerApp and it didn't work. Maybe the problem isn't with the ROS application but with the camera setup. Try to initialize the PylonViewerApp after the boot, before to the ROS Node. Because I've already had a similar problem, and I solved in this way.

---

Originally posted by [matheusns](https://answers.ros.org/users/29215/matheusns/) with karma: 111 on 2018-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0